# Focus to a object in square form using ios Camera?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, avfoundation

Actually I need a region over camera overlay like mostly of the QR code scanner app. 
And when a square box comes within it just focus and click picture from it. Any idea how to implement it. I was using the `UIIMAGEPICKER` class but after doing some googling I found that I need to use the AVFoundation framework. But unfortunately I am not the near one.

Any code or any tutorial will be helpful. Please let me know how can I implement this.

One more thing if i need to take picture can i make the picture only to the region size?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct. You will need to use `AV Foundation` to implement this. Have a look at the 'Using the Camera with AV Foundation' video from the [WWDC 2010 session videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/), to get an overview of the framework.

AvFoundation has no Dependancies on UIKit. So you will get some nice performance increases over using `UIImagePickerController`. It will also give you Full Access to the camera.

When using `AV Foundation` you are in control of the 'Device Capture Settings' i.e. `Flash` as well as `Focus Mode` and  `Exposure`; including their points of interest. Have a look at the [Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html) to see how to use these, or the device behaviour may differ from what you expected.

You can also download and example of an application that uses AV Foundation to implement the camera [here](https://github.com/beingmattlevy/avcam).

Once you're up and running with that, have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273) to get started with the overlay on the camera.

> One more thing if i need to take picture can i make the picture only to the region size?

Yes you will be able to implement this. You can also configure the `AVFoundation` session itself to output the lowest practical resolution.